# How to detect the slow implementations of OpenGL on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working on a game and due to the fact it was ported from Blackberry the project started with drawing on a Canvas. Now the game runs pretty well that way, but we want to use OpenGL draw textures on the newer phones, where available.

The problem is that most phone support the draw_texture extension even if in reality their performance is awful. As an example, the HTC Wildfire next to my computer with the Android PixelFlinger 1.2 runs at 5fps with opengl and 30 fps with Canvas.

So how can I detect under which condition to use Canvas over OpenGL? I can detect if the renderer is PixelFlinger for sure, but are there other hints? Other renderers to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about maintaining a blacklist of devices, and compare it to `android.os.Build.BOARD` to determine which rendering path to take.